# How to set margin of one element equal to height of other element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to set the `margin-top` of `div2` equal to height of `div1` using javascript (no matter how much the height is) and than div2 would be visible.

```css
.div1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.div2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Chances are someone is going to give you the answer anyways, but I'd strongly recommend always attempting the problem yourself before writing a question on Stack Overflow. You'll learn a lot more that way.

Comment: Why you need that ??? Don't use absolute position at all then

Comment: @Serlite Absolutely right. That is how we learn new things especially in programming.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
var div1Height = document.getElementsByClassName("div1")[0].style.height;
document.getElementsByClassName("div2")[0].style.margin = div1Height;
```

I have found [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) helpful (hint: try taking the time to *learn the language*).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery` that includes a lot of function so you write less code.

```
document.querySelector('.div2').style.marginTop = document.querySelector('.div2').style.height;
```

You can also use properties like clientHeight or offsetHeight :

```
`clientHeight` includes padding.
```

`offsetHeight` includes padding, scrollBar and borders.

You do it like this :

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('.div2')` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//If you use jquery then you can write code as follows.

$(document).ready(function(){

var height_of_div1 = $(".div1").css('height'); // Best way will be if you use id rather than class for this div

$(".div2").css('margin-top',height_of_div1);

});`
```

Comment: There is no jQuery tag in the question.

Comment: you can use this line in you head element <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>  or you can download this js page and can add to head tag.  https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using clientHeight

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JRoqVX

```
<style>
.div1{
  width:50%;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:red;
}
.div2{
   width:50%;
  height:100px;
   background-color:blue;
 }
</style>
<div class="div1">
  test 1
 </div>
<div class="div2">
  test 2
  </div>
<div onclick="test()">Test</div>
<script>
function test() {
  var div2 = document.querySelector(".div2");
  var div1 = document.querySelector(".div2");

  div2.style.marginTop = div1.clientHeight + "px";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Note that `querySelector` is *3 times slower* than `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use ids for such elements, otherwise if you want to do something like this with elements group, just use foreach loop.

```
var h = document.getElementsByClassName("div1")[0].offsetHeight;
document.getElementsByClassName("div2")[0].style.topMargin = h+"px";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
window.onload = () => {
    document.querySelector('.div2').style.marginTop = `${document.querySelector(".div1").offsetHeight}px`;
  }
```